# Using params with oc patch comand

Tags: bash, openshift, kubectl, json-patch

Trying to write an sh script with several oc patch commands and need to parametrize several values.
Now script looks like:

```
oc patch svc svc-ingressgateway --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/ports/-", "value": {"name": "http-8080","port": 8080} }]'
oc patch vs vs-ingressgateway --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/hosts/-", "value": "ingress-http-host.smth.com" }]'
oc patch gw gw-ingressgateway --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/servers/-", "value": { "hosts": ["ingress-http-host.smth.com"], "port": {"name":"http-8080", "number":8080,"protocol":"HTTP"} } }]'
```

Trying to do smth like this:

```
HTTP_HOST='ingress-http-host.smth.com'
HTTP_PORT='8080'
oc patch svc svc-ingressgateway --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/ports/-", "value": {"name": "http-${HTTP_PORT}","port": ${HTTP_PORT}} }]'
oc patch vs vs-ingressgateway --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/hosts/-", "value": ${HTTP_HOST} }]'
oc patch gw gw-ingressgateway --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/servers/-", "value": { "hosts": [${HTTP_HOST}], "port": {"name":"http-${HTTP_PORT}", "number":${HTTP_PORT},"protocol":"HTTP"} } }]'
```

but this is wrong, obviously, because the error appears:

`Error from server: admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: domain name "$HTTP_HOST" invalid (label "$HTTP_HOST" invalid) Error from server: admission webhook "pilot.validation.istio.io" denied the request: configuration is invalid: 2 errors occurred: * short names (non FQDN) are not allowed * domain name "$HTTP_HOST" invalid (label "$HTTP_HOST" invalid)`

Please, help, if you know how to do such things

Comment: did you try to run your script line by line to see from which line you get the exception?

Answer (score 2):

The error appears because the [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) of `${HTTP_PORT}` and `${HTTP_HOST}` is not done within single quotes. A way to fix this is ending the quotation just before and beginning a new one just after the parameter expansion. Besides, the braces are unneeded in this case. So, you can effectively replace `${HTTP_....}` with `'$HTTP_....'`